# Programming: Find bigger number if $x$ becomes little and find more little number if $x$ becomes bigger

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I don't know maths well, I need to ask this. I forgot many things and had improved my maths up to functions / polynomial. And apologize for my English.

I have integers between $1$ to $999$. The important part is $60$ to $210$ for me. Say this number is $x$ and its value is $150$. In this case I want to find number $0.20$

If $x = 70$ I want to find $0.60$

I mean we could say;

$x: 210$ is the highest number and $60$ is the smallest number.

y: $0.1$ is the smallest number and $0.60$ is the highest number.

If $x$ increases I want $y$ to decrease. If $x$ decreases I want $y$ to increase. How can I do this? I hope I'll get a simple fix.

Comment: What scale are you using? If you did it linearly, you'd get $y = (210-x)/300 + 0.1$, but the values you provided don't match this linear scale.

Comment: I couldn't exactly understand what you mean but it may be linear based on the top and bottom values I've given.

Comment: The function I wrote down just takes the range 60 to 210, flips it and shrinks it to the scale 0.1 to 0.6.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar your formula works well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one $y={{x-30}\over 300}$